# Is there away to capture a marker focus event?

Tags: google-maps, focus

I want to capture a marker focus event so that I can change the marker icon when the markers are being tabbed through.

Basically instead of this:
`marker.addListener("click", () => {});`
or this:
`marker.addListener("mouseover", () => {});`

I want this:
`marker.addListener("focus", () => {});`

I am trying to make the map more accessible and the default focus-visible state that adds a blue outline to the pin is hard to target in CSS plus it is more subtle than I want.

Is there a way to add a marker focus event for keyboard navigation use?

Using the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-accessibility

I tried these various events and none of them worked on keyboard navigation:

```
    marker.addListener("mouseover", () => {
        alert('mouseover');
    });
    marker.addListener("mousedown", () => {
        alert('mousedown');
    });
    marker.addListener("mouseout", () => {
        alert('mouseout');
    });
    marker.addListener("mouseup", () => {
        alert('mouseup');
    });
    marker.addListener("cursor_changed", () => {
        alert('focus');
    });
    marker.addListener("focus", () => {
        alert('focus');
    });
    marker.addListener("focusin", () => {
        alert('focusin');
    });
    marker.addListener("focusout", () => {
        alert('focusout');
    });
```

The "click" event (which is in the Maps API documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events), does work as expected with tab navigation upon pressing the Return key:

```
    marker.addListener("click", () => {
        alert('click');
    });
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/charitygrace/jxsqv1gh/

Comment: The Legacy Markers of Google Maps Javascript API only supports its own built in `addListener` method which does not have a 'focus' event. see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events . But as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers#AdvancedMarkerElement.addEventListener), the new Advanced Marker can be used with Javascript's `addEventListener` in which the 'focus' event is available. I'm still trying to make a reproducible example for you but maybe you can try this out also on your end.

Comment: Thanks @Yrll I don't want to get into beta right now, but I'll consider it in the future. I agree that I don't think this is possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the div element. Something like this:

```
let div = document.querySelector("div[aria-label='1. Boynton Pass']")

div.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
  console.log('focus');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The focus event on the div doesn't seem to fire even though the div is correctly grabbed after the map is idle and after a settimeout. Here's my trial fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/charitygrace/da0g1Lmu/38/. I'm not going to spend more time on this.